# renaming and removing a file doesn't work just in the first iteration (C)

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I created a program that creates a binary file, inserts data of employees (code, name, salary).
Then the program increases the salary of each employee by the user input, and check if the salary is higher than the threshold. If so, the employee will be deleted from the file.

Everything works almost perfect, but there is one problem.. I made a solution for two cases:

If there is no file in place, create one, then update it - 100% working.

else (if there is already a file exist), ask the user if he would like to edit it. (if he chooses "no", then the program will create and new file). Either of the options, while getting into the update part, for some reason, it doesn't work, and no change has been made.. the program prints the old file.
**but**, If I close the window and run again the program, for the second time, **it works**.

I could see that the temp.dat file that the program creates still exists on the first iteration.

Any suggestions?

main:

```
void Ex1()
{
    char filename[13] = "employee.dat";
    char c=NULL;
    float threshold = 5000;
    FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (fin == NULL)
    {
        printf("Creating a new file.. \n");
        fin = fopen(filename, "wb"); //creating a new blank file
        fclose(fin);
        get_Employee(filename);
        printf("Okay, this is what we have:\n");
        print_Bin_File(filename);
        printf("Now, let's increase the salary!\n");
        updateSalary(filename, threshold);
        printf("The updated file:\n");
        print_Bin_File(filename);
    }
    else
    {
        while (c != 'Y' || c != 'y' || c != 'N' || c != 'n')
        {
            printf("There is already an existing file:\n");
            print_Bin_File(filename);
            printf("Do you wish to update the current file? (Y/N)\n");
            rewind(stdin);
            c = getchar();
            rewind(stdin);
            if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
            {
                fclose(fin);
                printf("Ok, let's increase the salary!\n");
                updateSalary(filename, threshold);
                print_Bin_File(filename);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (c == 'N' || c == 'n')
                {
                    printf("Creating a new file.. \n");
                    fin = fopen(filename, "wb"); //creating a new blank file
                    fclose(fin);
                    get_Employee(filename);
                    printf("Okay, this is what we have:\n");
                    print_Bin_File(filename);
                    printf("Now, let's increase the salary!\n");
                    updateSalary(filename, threshold);
                    print_Bin_File(filename);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    printf("invalid input\n");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

update function:

```
void updateSalary(char* filename, float threshold)
{
    employee temp;
    char c;
    float increase;
    FILE *fup = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    FILE *ftmp = fopen("temp.dat", "wb+");
    if (fup == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to read the file\n");
        return;
    }
    while (fread(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, fup)) //fread will return 0 when reaching EOF - safer then using (!feof)
    {
        printf("How big is the increase to %s's salary?\n", temp.name);
        scanf("%f", &increase);
        temp.salary += increase;

        if (temp.salary<threshold)
        {
            fwrite(&temp, sizeof(employee), 1, ftmp);
        }
    }
    fclose(ftmp);
    fclose(fup);

remove(filename);
rename("temp.dat", filename);`enter code here`
}
```

**EDIT:**
The fix was to add `fclose(fin);` before `fin = fopen(filename, "wb");`.

Comment: Try `fclose(fin);` just before doing `fin = fopen(filename, "wb");` in the case where the file exists but the user wants to truncate it.

Comment: @4386427 Its just working! Thanks

Comment: Ofek or @4386427 please make an answer or delete the question, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Yunnosch I don't want to answer as I can't explain exactly what happens when you `fopen` a file with wb while the file is already open with rb. Doing that seems bad to me but... well, I wasn't sure. So my comment was mainly a guess. Feel free to provide the answer if you like.

Comment: @4386427 Good point. If you cannot explain then answering would not be appropriate. So this is now free for all (without taking away anything from you).

Comment: You need to check **all** return values from **all** calls to system functions. If you are on Windows, and you try to do this  `FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "rb"); fin = fopen(filename, "wb");` the second `fopen` will fail and you will never know that and spend hours debugging your program.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the code, I assumed that if there was an unsuccessful attempt to **read** the file, (`if (fin == NULL)`), then the pointer of the file (`fin`) would also be "closed" (as fclose(); does), and I could easily write a new file.

I haven't read enough about fopen(); and fclose(); functions, but it seems that **, if you want to check if there was a successful attempt,** to read the file, and then write one, you have to use fclose(); before after you read the file, either it was successful or not successful.

updated main:

```
void Ex1()
{
    char filename[13] = "employee.dat";
    char c=NULL;
    float threshold = 5000;
    FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (fin == NULL)
    {
        printf("Creating a new file.. \n");
        fclose(fin);
        fin = fopen(filename, "wb"); //creating a new blank file
        fclose(fin);
        get_Employee(filename);
        printf("Okay, this is what we have:\n");
        print_Bin_File(filename);
        printf("Now, let's increase the salary!\n");
        updateSalary(filename, threshold);
        printf("The updated file:\n");
        print_Bin_File(filename);
    }
    else
    {
        while (c != 'Y' || c != 'y' || c != 'N' || c != 'n')
        {
            printf("There is already an existing file:\n");
            print_Bin_File(filename);
            printf("Do you wish to update the current file? (Y/N)\n");
            rewind(stdin);
            c = getchar();
            rewind(stdin);
            if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y')
            {
                fclose(fin);
                printf("Ok, let's increase the salary!\n");
                updateSalary(filename, threshold);
                print_Bin_File(filename);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (c == 'N' || c == 'n')
                {
                    printf("Creating a new file.. \n");
                    fclose(fin);
                    fin = fopen(filename, "wb"); //creating a new blank file
                    fclose(fin);
                    get_Employee(filename);
                    printf("Okay, this is what we have:\n");
                    print_Bin_File(filename);
                    printf("Now, let's increase the salary!\n");
                    updateSalary(filename, threshold);
                    print_Bin_File(filename);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    printf("invalid input\n");

            }
        }
    }

}
```